# In GWT, how to reset the URL when the user hits "Cancel" in the navigation confirmation dialog?

Tags: java, gwt

In my GWT application, I want to ask a user confirmation when he navigates out of the current application, *i.e.* by entering a URL or closing the browser. This is typically done by registering a `ClosingHandler` and setting the desired dialog message in the `onWindowClosing` method. This seems to work well.

However, if the user tries to navigate say to `http://www.gmail.com` (by typing it in the URL bar) and hits **Cancel** to indicate he doesn't want to navigate, then my app keeps running but the browser's URL bar keeps indicating `http://www.gmail.com`. This causes a number of problems later in my application and will give the wrong result if the user bookmarks the page.

Is there a way to automatically reset the URL when the user presses **Cancel**?

Or, alternatively, is there a way to detect the user pressed the **Cancel** button? If so, is there a way to set the URL without triggering a `ValueChangeEvent`? (I could add some logic to prevent this, but I'd rather use a built-in mechanism if it exists.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this. It looks like GWT DeferredCommand are executed after the confirmation window has been closed. This, combined with Hilbrand's answer above, give me exactly what I want. Here is exactly what I do:

```
  public final void onWindowClosing(Window.ClosingEvent event) {
    event.setMessage(onLeaveQuestion);
    DeferredCommand.addCommand( new Command() {
      public void execute() {
        Window.Location.replace(currentLocation);
      }
    });
  }
```

Where `currentLocation` is obtained by calling `Window.Location.getHref()` every time the history token changes.

Comment: After some experimentation, this can cause an infinite loop in Firefox or the latest Chrome. For details, see: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/issues/detail?id=315

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this works but did you try: `History.newItem(History.getToken(), false);` to reset the URL? It does set the history token without triggering a new history item.

Comment: Thanks! This doesn't work exactly, but by storing the previous token I'm able to solve the problem when the user navigates within the application (because in this case, I know when the user presses Cancel). Now if only I had a way of knowing after the onWindowClosing dialog. Maybe with a timer? (yuck!)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom PlaceController and replacing the token in the url. Not an ideal solution but it works!

`if (warning == null || Window.confirm(warning)) {
    where = newPlace;
    eventBus.fireEvent(new PlaceChangeEvent(newPlace));
    currentToken = History.getToken();
} else {
    // update the url when user clicks cancel in confirm popup.
    History.replaceItem(currentToken, false);
}`